# How can I enable users to play video using my app?

Tags: android, video, android-3.0-honeycomb

Just spent a couple of hours last night developing a pretty sweet video player for Honeycomb, and now I'd of course love for people to be able to use it.

How can I make my application listen for / receive "video play broadcasts"?

I'm guessing it's got something to do with the `manifest.xml` file, but I was unable to find anything about it on the Android Developer site.

I've tried using the following without much success:

```
<receiver android:name=".VideoPlayer">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW">
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I eventually solved this one myself with the following code in my `manifest.xml` file:

```
    <!-- Video player -->
    <activity android:name=".VideoPlayer" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/BlackHolo" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="rtsp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: i used your above code , but my app is not showing on clicking some video URL? i tested with this url http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1211/sample_iTunes.mov please help me in solving the problem

Comment: Does this work for you on Marshmallow? it works for me on Android 5 and below but not 6.0.1.

Comment: Yes it is working for me i got my app icon in open with dialog , but how to pass video path with it's click ?

Answer (score 1):

Video players are usually implemented as activities. Hence, you would use an `<activity>` element for that action and MIME type, not a `<receiver>` element. You might also want to specify both the `DEFAULT` and `BROWSABLE` categories -- the latter would be needed for links clicked on in a Web browser.

Comment: I used this code in my manifest to register my activity: http://pastie.org/9257525 But it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: @berserk: Add the `DEFAULT` category, as mentioned in my answer. If you have further concerns on this topic, please ask a fresh Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Still not working, I guess I must post new question.