# Android open video with custom app

Tags: android, video, popup, android-video-player

one of my project I was develop video player app for android.

- when we browse video using android device file explorer and select it then usually 
  popup a window and show the possible video player apps.

as showing red area in this image

[image: as showing red area in this image]

In my case I wanna show my video player app just like this red area apps showing. how can I do this. Is there any way to do this in programmatically in android.

Comment: If the given Answer is correct then accept it (mark as solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to mention intent filter for your activity that plays video,so that it is visible for other apps.

you can read more about that here
[Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

example:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
 </intent-filter>
```

[you can also see the answer given by @Michell Bak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370875/how-can-i-enable-users-to-play-video-using-my-app)

Comment: Thanx... for answering it's working. can you pls tell how to get selected video file path to activity class.

Comment: add category <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" /> in  the intent filter and try to get the uri from intent , you will receive in your videoPlaying activity

Comment: I try it.. But got null data. has any idea.

Comment: have you added the <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" /> ?

Comment: yes.. I do. but   `getIntent().getData(); ` return null.

Comment: If I try to print the intent this is what I am getting :        Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://media/external/file/139972 typ=video/mp4 flg=0x13000000 cmp=com.example.videoplayer.AndroidVideoViewExample }

Comment: As you can see I am getting  content ----> content://media/external/file/139972. you have to query the media store for that video file

Comment: In nougat you will get content,like this :content://media/external/file/139972   , while in marshmallow and below you will get file uri like this: file:///storage/emulated/0/Video_Encryption/Original_Videos/1.mp4 .

Comment: try to print the intent then see what you are getting

Comment: Thanks for your helping..  It's work now. As you say I query the media store for that video file. Thanks again...